# Large POD as tuple for sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, tuples, containers

I have a POD with about 30 members of various types and I will be wanting to store thousands of the PODs in a container, and then sort that container by one of those members.

For example:

```
 struct Person{
   int idNumber;
   ....many other members
 }
```

Thousands of `Person` objects which I want to sort by `idNumber` or by any other member I choose to sort by.

I've been researching this for a while today and it seems the most efficient, or at least, simplest, solution to this is not use `struct` at all, and rather use `tuple` for which I can pass an index number to a custom comparison functor for use in `std::sort`. (An example on [this page](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/275617-stl-stdmap-and-sorting-using-value_compare/) shows one way to implement this type of sort easily, but does so on a single member of a `struct` which would make templating this not so easy since you must refer to the member by name, rather than by index which the `tuple` provides.)

My two-part question on this approach is 1) Is it acceptable for a tuple to be fairly large, with dozens of members? and 2) Is there an equally elegant solution for continuing to use `struct` instead of `tuple` for this?

Comment: You want to avoid to write a custom comparison function for each of the members, or what's the problem here?

Comment: Correct, easier to have one comparison function that will work on any member (they nearly all floats anyway) and thus refer to members as indexes in that function rather than by member names, which would require separate functions for each menber

Comment: Use a pointer to members to dereference the correct data for comparison.

Comment: @PeterWood I'd appreciate an elaboration on that as an answer, if possible.

Comment: @Fellowshee: all three answers use pointer-to-members. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a comparator that stores a pointer to member internaly so it knows which member to take for comparison:

```
struct POD {
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
    long l;
    double d;
    short s;
};

template<typename C, typename T>
struct Comp {

    explicit Comp(T C::* p) : ptr(p) {}

    bool operator()(const POD& p1, const POD& p2) const
    {
        return p1.*ptr < p2.*ptr;
    }

private:
    T C::* ptr;
};

// helper function to make a comparator easily

template<typename C, typename T>
Comp<C,T> make_comp( T C::* p)
{
    return Comp<C,T>(p);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<POD> v;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), make_comp(&POD::i));
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), make_comp(&POD::d));
    // etc...
}
```

To further generalize this, make `make_comp` take a custom comparator, so you can have greater-than and other comparisons.

Comment: +1, pretty much what I did except I chose to pass the pointer-to-member as a template argument (and I didn't actually write the comparator, just the accessor -- lazy me ^_^).

Comment: switching to this answer since it goes furthest in solving the final goal, many thanks.

Comment: I just noticed that when you call `make_comp()` with `&POD::i` that is satisfying the parameter `C::* p` in that function, but how is the parameter `T` getting passed in?

Comment: @Fellowshee `T C::*` is one type - pointer to a T member of class C. Both T and C are deduced by the compiler - when we say `&POD::i` it deduces C as `POD` and T as `int`.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is it acceptable for a tuple to be fairly large, with dozens of members?

Yes it is acceptable. However it won't be easy to maintain since all you'll have to work with is an index within the tuple, which is very akin to a magic number. The best you could get is reintroduce a name-to-index mapping using an `enum` which is hardly maintainable either.

> 2) Is there an equally elegant solution for continuing to use struct instead of tuple for this?

You can easily write a template function to access a specific struct member (to be fair, I didn't put much effort into it, it's more a proof of concept than anything else so that you get an idea how it can be done):

```
template<typename T, typename R, R T::* M>
R get_member(T& o) {
  return o.*M;
}

struct Foo {
  int i;
  bool j;
  float k;
};

int main() {
  Foo f = { 3, true, 3.14 };
  std::cout << get_member<Foo, float, &Foo::k>(f) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

From there, it's just as easy to write a generic comparator which you can use at your leisure (I'll leave it to you as an exercise). This way you can still refer to your members by name, yet you don't need to write a separate comparator for each member.

Comment: that's some gnarly templating at work there, thanks, very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template to extract the sort key:

```
struct A
{
    std::string name;
    int a, b;
};

template<class Struct, typename T, T Struct::*Member>
struct compare_member
{
    bool operator()(const Struct& lh, const Struct& rh)
    {
        return lh.*Member < rh.*Member;
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> values;
    std::sort(begin(values), end(values), compare_member<A, int, &A::a>());
}
```

Maybe you want to have a look at [boost::multi_index_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) which is a very powerful container if you want to index (sort) object by different keys.

Comment: Is this similar to what Peter Wood suggests in the comments to the question?

Comment: It is, I was just typing it up (c:

Comment: @Fellowshee Yes.. all answer are very similar. See the link to boost multi_index_container, if you want a even more powerful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which can use a pointer to a `Person` member data to use for comparison:

```
 std::sort(container.begin(), container.end(), Compare(&Person::idNumber));
```

Where `Compare` is:

```
template<typename PointerToMemberData>
struct Compare {
     Compare(PointerToMemberData pointerToMemberData) :
     pointerToMemberData(pointerToMemberData) {
     }

     template<typename Type
     bool operator()(Type lhs, Type rhs) {
         return lhs.*pointerToMemberData < rhs.*pointerToMemberData
     }

     PointerToMemberData pointerToMemberData;
};
```